# Using JQuery Bootstrap in a reloadable Ajax Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an ordering system which allows staff to record orders and track their status from ordered to dispatched. The problem that we have however is that when viewing orders, another staff member on another computer may change orders. This wont register until a page refresh is carried out.

To address this I was hoping to use this script....
http://www.michaelfretz.com/2010/04/21/using-ajax-to-load-data-from-php-into-your-website/

I have managed to get it working great within twitter bootstrap. On slower connections, the page loads and says 'please wait while data loads' until the data is loaded.

The problem I have however is that I cannot get javascript to work within the reloading section. I was hoping to use bootstrap tooltips. The user can hover over an order id and it will popup with the order contents. It works great outside of the reloading section, but within I cannot get it to work.

I have tried loading the jquery, and bootstrap tooltip javascript within the loading section, but even this did not work. This would have made it very slow anyhow though.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can use Bootstrap Tooltips with the Ajax reloading PHP document.

Thanks

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be loading dynamic content, bind your handlers to the closest parent that doesn't change, and then add a filter to only select the elements you want to handle.

So, by why of example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="igetinjectedwithdynamiccontent">
        ...
        <a href="#" class="btn">IMA BUTTON</a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'a.btn', function(event){
    // handle click event for anchors of class 'btn'
});
```

This will successfully bind `onclick` handlers to any Bootstrap buttons in the `parent` div, regardless of whether they existed on page load or were added dynamically.

Comment: Ok... So that works great. If I put the button within the dynamic ajax content and the jquery in the footer. Ofcourse, it only works for 1 minute which is the timeout for the dynamic material. Also is there a way to make it work on load, rather than pressing a button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help answering this question... I have got it figured now. Didn't even know what to search for before asking the question.

I could have either used an onload simulator which will simulate pressing the button. Should Work.

I opted however for instead using the selecter option which Apparently is just an alternative to the jquery 'Live'

For those who are in the same boat I was. Paste this in your page after loading JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 ( function($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

 $('body').tooltip({
                 selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
         });

});

 } ) ( jQuery );

 </script>
```

Sorry about the indentation .... Stupid 4 spaces thingy :)

This script will continue loading even if the content is changed.